# Python Firebase Admin SDK - DefaultCredentialsError

Tags: python, firebase-authentication, raspberry-pi, firebase-admin

I'm having trouble setting up credentials when initializing Firebase Admin SDK for Python. Taking inspiration from [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-python/blob/master/machine-learning/manage-ml.py#L14-L20), I'm setting it up like this:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore

cred = credentials.Certificate('./serviceAccountKey.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.Client()
```

...but this results in:

```
raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application.
```

The only way I can get this to work is to create a `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable like this first:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="serviceAccountKey.json"
```

For the path to `credentials.Certificate(path)`, I've tried `'./serviceAccountKey.json'`, `'serviceAccountKey.json'`, and even an absolute path, `'/home/pi/projects/serviceAccountKey.json'`

I'm doing this inside of a Raspberry Pi.

How can I get the credentials to work without having to explicitly set the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable?

Comment: have you tried putting your json file directly into the initialize_app() method? often it doesn't need to be created as a certificate since it relies on a different data structure

Comment: I just tried it and got this error: `ValueError: Illegal Firebase credential provided. App must be initialized with a valid credential instance.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your environment variable locally with `environ`

```py
import os
>>> os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]
    './serviceAccountKey.json'
```

or

```py
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = './serviceAccountKey.json'
```